# Evaluate JavaScript file for runtime/loading errors from command line

Tags: javascript, command-line

We're using requirejs to compile our web application into a single uglified js file.

Sometimes the includes are missing a define so that the code is executed in the wrong order during startup and the application throws exception and halts.

I'm looking for a tool so that I can do basic testing of this in our CI environment.

PhantomJS looked like a possible winner, but I haven't been able to get something working yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yes, PhantomJS was the answer, just not doing it the right way :) Enjoy.

```
var fs = require( 'fs' );
var system = require( 'system' );
if( system.args.length === 2 ) {
    console.log( 'Missing script arguments...' );
    phantom.exit( 10 );
}

var server = require( 'webserver' ).create();
var service = server.listen( 8080, function( request, response ) {
    response.statusCode = 200;

    if( request.url == "/script" ) {
        response.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'text/javascript' );
        try {
            response.write( fs.read( system.args[1] ) );
        } catch( e ) {
            console.log( e );
            phantom.exit(2);
        }
    } else {
        response.write( '<html><script type="text/javascript" src="/script"></script><body>Tjoff!</body></html>' );
    }

    response.close();
});

var page = require( 'webpage' ).create();
page.onError = function( msg, trace ) {
    console.log( 'ERROR: ' + msg );
    phantom.exit(1);
};
page.open( 'http://localhost:8080', function( status ) {
    setTimeout( function() {
        phantom.exit();
    }, 2500 );
});
```